Movie about a self-harming girl who is kidnapped
I watched this ~10 years ago on TV.
In the film, a girl uses pieces of broken mirror to cut her wrists. Her mum notices and has all the knives and sharp objects removed from the house.
The girl is then kidnapped. Her kidnappers put her on a bed and notice all the scars on her legs from her self-harming. They remark that she enjoys the pain and so they cut her some more.
I believe the girl is blonde and she was possibly raped.

We'll need a bit more information than this to go on.  Possible date? Language? etc?

What is self-cutting anyway ? You said that kidnappers cut on her legs.

Self injury, when you cut your wrist or wains with a razor.

Language is english.

@mike is it the one, pointed out in the answer ?

Hi, thanks for the answer, but it's not that one.

I got some new information. She actually saw the movie about 10 years ago on tv, so it was back then a couple years old. Girl in the movie also used pieces of broken mirror to cut her wrists, when her mom was taken all the knifes and sharp objects out of the house. And when she was kidnaped, they put her on bed, and they saw scars on her legs, saying that she enjoys the pain, so they cut her abit more. Excuse my english, it's not my primary language.

@mike update the information in question itself please

do you remember how or why the girl got kidnapped...?  or if she died?  or if there were drugs involved?  I'm not finding anything.

Sounds like 'painful secrets' (or 'secret cutting'). But she wasn't kidnapped, she went to an apartment for sex with her ex but he had friends and they commented on her scars. After, she cut and went to the hospital.
Or maybe 'The girl next door' but I don't think she cut herself. She was blonde. She was locked in the basement, beat, raped at some point. It's based off of 'an American crime' 
